# What is causing: Error Google_OAuth2.php on line 115

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

**EDIT**
This particular error was from my mistake of not setting up the application correctly.  It's a situation where, even though the code works now, I have no idea what caused the problem, and I'd need to get deep into the inner workings to figure it out.
**end**

I'm running the Google Drive API QuickStart example code for PHP from Windows7 operating system command line.  Here is the code that I am running:

[Google Drive API Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php#step_3_set_up_the_sample)

I can get through obtaining an authorization URL, that will successfully return my access token.  But after entering the access token, something goes wrong in the `Google_OAuth2.php file supplied by Google to complete the authorization.

Here is a more complete error msg:

> Fatal error:
>
> Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'Error fetching
>   OAuth2 access token,
>
> message: 'invalid_request'' in
>   C:\google-api-php-client\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php:115 Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\google-api-php-client\src\Google_Client.php(127):
>   Google_OAuth2->authenticate(Array, '4/HW2t_MZIxatq6...')
>
> #1 C:\Users\Gigabyte\MyWebsite\Take_Validation.php(10):
>   Google_Client->authenticate('4/HW2t_MZIxatq6...')
>
> #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\google-api-php-client\src\auth\Google_OAuth2.php on line 115

This is part of the code from the `Google_OAuth2.php` file:  Line 115 is the last statement `throw new Google_AuthException`

```
  /**
   * @param $service
   * @param string|null $code
   * @throws Google_AuthException
   * @return string
   */
  public function authenticate($service, $code = null) {
    if (!$code && isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $code = $_GET['code'];
    }

    if ($code) {
      // We got here from the redirect from a successful authorization grant, fetch the access token
      $request = Google_Client::$io->makeRequest(new Google_HttpRequest(self::OAUTH2_TOKEN_URI, 'POST', array(), array(
          'code' => $code,
          'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
          'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUri,
          'client_id' => $this->clientId,
          'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret
      )));

      if ($request->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
        $this->setAccessToken($request->getResponseBody());
        $this->token['created'] = time();
        return $this->getAccessToken();
      } else {
        $response = $request->getResponseBody();
        $decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);
        if ($decodedResponse != null && $decodedResponse['error']) {
          $response = $decodedResponse['error'];
        }
        throw new Google_AuthException("Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: '$response'", $request->getResponseHttpCode());
      }
    }
```

Obviously the error comes before line 115.  Line 115 is just printing out that an error occurred somewhere before.  I don't know if it's the code, or something I'm doing wrong.  I know that every time a new URL authorization request is put in, I get a different access code back.  My client secret and client ID shouldn't ever need to change.  I have no idea how to make this work at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get the example code from Google to run.  I think the problem was that I was using the wrong Client ID and Client Secret.  Well, actually I was using the wrong Client ID Credential application type all together.  I think I was using the `web application` for an `installed application`.  Well, I'm glad it was my error, and not a problem with the API.  The `Native Application` is for the `Installed Application`.  I guess those terms get used interchangeably.  And the `Installed Application` is for running PHP from the `Command Line`.  The other thing I noticed, is that when the `Native Application` client ID is created, you can NOT change the Redirect URIs.   They are automatically set to:

```
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
http://localhost
```